# Table Cell sizing in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, resize

This is a bit of a weird one to explain but I'm trying to create a little interactive house thingy using tables (I know, shame on me) and images with jQuery. There are four table cells which, when clicked, resize to take up the space of all four (see the image in the link for a better idea) but in IE, the bottom cells will resize but a weird gap is created above them (see screenshots on the right of the attached image). When the cells are taken back to their normal size (by clicking the stairs on the left), they display fine.

Screenshots: http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=2d1v0ktgb4m1a6c1lg6h.png

Here's the code that's doing the resizing:

```
$('td').click(function(){
  var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
  var thisIMG = '<img src="' + thisID + '.jpg" usemap="#' + thisID + '-map">';
  $(this).animate({'height':'240px','width':'280px'},500);
  $('td').not(this).animate({'height':'0px','width':'0px'},500);
  $(this).html(thisIMG);
});
$('#tableStairs').click(function(){
  $('td').animate({'height':'120px','width':'140px'},500);
  $('td').html('');
});
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks,

Ash

Comment: Without a complete jsFiddle for this, it's going to be impossible for anyone but you to troubleshoot. We need CSS styling and full HTML markup including local copies of the PNGs. And what version of IE are you testing this with? Remember, <IE8 has serious box model flaws.

Comment: Fair shout - I've just tried to set up a jsFiddle but it doesn't work at all in IE. I'm testing with IE9 and I've tried different browser modes through the dev panel but it doesn't work in any of them (IE8 is doing exactly as IE9 is doing, IE7 completely screwed the whole thing up layout-wise but I'm not worried about that for now).